# How to convert a Shortcode into a Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

**1. Shortcode (working)**

I have made a Shortcode which display the current weatherinformations from yahoo. There was 3 Files (simple-pie.inc, simple-pie-yahoo.inc and yahooweather.php) and I grabed the content of these files and pasted it inside my function.php – works good!

This looks so and got more then 16.000 Lines of Code:

```
// Add Shortcode for weather
function get_rohrau_wetter() {
    content of simple-pie.inc
    content of simple-pie-yahoo.inc
    content of yahooweather.php -> return "weather-html"
}
add_shortcode( 'rohrauwetter', 'get_rohrau_wetter' );
```

**2. Plugin (no clue where to start)**

All I want to do is making a Plugin out of my working shortcode to get that "wall-of-code" out of my function.php and of course for better reuseability. Also I think so it will be possible to turn the simple-pie cache to "on" for faster processing…

My Question is: **How do I convert my Shortcode into an Plugin?**

Comment: Off-topic, but as I just did something similiar: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/30/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: It's all in the docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: @brasofilo …i know but i dont understand these docs, thats why i asked here for help or maybe a template for a shortcode-plugin…

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would the plugin handbook: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/header-requirements/

But the cheap and nasty way to place it into a plugin, create a directory for your plugin, create a index.php (realistically it can be any name) file. Add this in

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name:  WordPress.org Plugin
Plugin URI:   https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/
Description:  Basic WordPress Plugin Header Comment
Version:      20160911
Author:       WordPress.org
Author URI:   https://developer.wordpress.org/
License:      GPL2
License URI:  https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain:  wporg
Domain Path:  /languages
*/
```

Then underneath it add in your above functions. Obviously Change out the text to suit yourself so that you can identify the plugin. Then upload it too your plugins directory.

As I said, this is the cheap and nasty way to set it up. I would advise to have a look at the plugin handbook I linked to above. Also Using OOP plugin development is advised, a good starting point is Tom McFarlin tutorial on tutsplus: https://code.tutsplus.com/series/object-oriented-programming-in-wordpress--cms-699 .. and after that well worth looking at https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate and https://wppb.me/ hope that all helps.